# Using Apache Bench with different post data per request

Tags: apache-2.4, benchmark

I'm looking to use `ab` to obtain some performance metrics on my site. I'm looking to send POST requests to my desired URL, however I'd like to change the values for the POST params for each request.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ab does not support what you need, at least till the version included in apache 2.4.23. You can use other tools though there are plenty to choose from, JMeter comes me in mind right now. You can even easily script it.

Comment: That's a shame `ab` can't do this, I'll give JMeter a look Thanks